# Change correctly from React 16.13.1 version to React 16.8.0 version for hooks

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hooks, react-dom

I know this question is similar to others already asked, but I can't find a solution in the answers. I'm having trouble when updating the react and react-dom versions in my app. I'm constructing a web page with **material-ui**, and the case is that a lot of its components are hooks, so that in my app I need to use functions instead of classes. That's ok, but the problem is that when I compile the app the next error appears:

**Hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component.**

The next code is the one that throws this error:

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";
import Tabs from "@material-ui/core/Tabs";
import Tab from "@material-ui/core/Tab";
import FlagIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Flag";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import Box from "@material-ui/core/Box";
import TitleCard from '../TitleCard/TitleCard';
import PhaseCard from '../PhaseCard/PhaseCard';
import BusinessSharpIcon from '@material-ui/icons/BusinessSharp';
import AssignmentSharpIcon from '@material-ui/icons/AssignmentSharp';
import RedFlagCard from '../RedFlagCard/RedFlagCard';
import InfoCard from '../InfoCard/InfoCard';
import CalculationCard from '../CalculationCard/CalculationCard';
import FiltersCard from '../Filters/FiltersCard/FiltersCard';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    width: "100%",
    backgroundColor: '#303030'
  },
  flags: {
    color: '#26c6da'
  },
  indicator: {
    backgroundColor: '#26c6da'
  },
  text: {
    color: 'white'
  }
}));

function TabPanel(props) {
  const { children, value, index, ...other } = props;

  return (
    <div
      role="tabpanel"
      hidden={value !== index}
      id={`scrollable-force-tabpanel-${index}`}
      aria-labelledby={`scrollable-force-tab-${index}`}
      {...other}
    >
      {value === index && (
        <Box p={3}>
          <Typography>{children}</Typography>
        </Box>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

TabPanel.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node,
  index: PropTypes.any.isRequired,
  value: PropTypes.any.isRequired
};

function a11yProps(index) {
  return {
    id: `scrollable-force-tab-${index}`,
    "aria-controls": `scrollable-force-tabpanel-${index}`
  };
}

export default function CenteredTabs(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div>
      <Paper className={classes.root}>
        <Tabs
          value={props.val}
          onChange={props.changed}
          classes={{
            indicator: classes.indicator
          }}
          centered
        >
          <Tab label="Bandera 1" className={classes.flags} icon={<FlagIcon />} {...a11yProps(0)} />
          <Tab label="Bandera 2" className={classes.flags} icon={<FlagIcon />} {...a11yProps(1)} />
          <Tab label="Bandera 3" className={classes.flags} icon={<FlagIcon />} {...a11yProps(2)} />
          <Tab label="Bandera 4" className={classes.flags} icon={<FlagIcon />} {...a11yProps(3)} />
          <Tab label="Bandera 5" className={classes.flags} icon={<FlagIcon />} {...a11yProps(4)} />
        </Tabs>
      </Paper>
      <TabPanel value={props.val} index={0}>
        <TitleCard title="Tiempo insuficiente para la preparación de ofertas competitivas"/>
        <PhaseCard phase="Licitación" icon=<BusinessSharpIcon/>/>
        <RedFlagCard
          info=<p>Un periodo de tiempo insuficiente no permitirá a todos los licitantes interesados preparar y presentar ofertas de calidad. Los licitantes que hayan sido “informados” antes de la apertura pública pueden tener ventaja injusta teniendo más tiempo para preparar las ofertas.</p>/>
        <InfoCard
          info=<p>
            <li>ID del concurso</li>
            <li>Método de contratación</li>
            <li>Fecha de inicio del concurso</li>
            <li>Fecha final del concurso</li>
          </p>
        />
        <CalculationCard info="Fecha final del concurso - Fecha incial del concurso"/>
        <FiltersCard />
      </TabPanel>
      <TabPanel value={props.val} index={1}>
        <TitleCard title="Bajo número de oferentes en los procesos competitivos"/>
        <PhaseCard phase="Licitación" icon=<BusinessSharpIcon/>/>
        <RedFlagCard
          info=<p>Un mayor número de oferentes por licitación puede indicar que los procesos son más competitivos y confiables, tanto en la forma del proceso (abierta en lugar de cerrada) como en el nivel de competencia dentro de cada proceso.</p>/>
        <InfoCard
          info=<p>
            <li>ID del concurso</li>
            <li>Método de contratación</li>
            <li>Información sobre los oferentes</li>
          </p>
        />
        <CalculationCard info="Obteniendo el promedio del número de licitantes de los procesos de contratación abierta"/>
      </TabPanel>
      <TabPanel value={props.val} index={2}>
        <TitleCard title="Bajo porcentaje de licitaciones ganadas mediante procesos competitivos"/>
        <PhaseCard phase="Licitación" icon=<BusinessSharpIcon/>/>
        <RedFlagCard
          info=<p>Un mayor porcentaje total de ofertas adjudicadas a través de procesos competitivos puede indicar una mayor apertura en compra pública. El uso de procedimientos competitivos puede permitir que los licitantes potenciales tengan mayor acceso a los procesos de contratación pública y, por lo tanto, puede resultar en una mayor competencia der mercado.</p>/>
        <InfoCard
          info=<p>
            <li>ID del concurso</li>
            <li>Método de contratación</li>
            <li>Valor del concurso</li>
          </p>
        />
        <CalculationCard info="Número total de procesos de contratación adjudicados por métodos competitivos / número total de procesos de contratación"/>
      </TabPanel>
      <TabPanel value={props.val} index={3}>
        <TitleCard title="Gran diferencia porcentual entre el monto de adjudicación del contrato y el monto final del contrato"/>
        <PhaseCard phase="Adjudicación/Contrato" icon=<AssignmentSharpIcon/>/>
        <RedFlagCard
          info=<p>
            Una diferencia significativa entre el precio de adjudicación y el precio final del contrato puede ser señal de:
              <li>Existencia de acuerdos "a puerta cerrada" entre proveedores y compradores. En algunos casos, el licitante ofrece un precio artificialmente bajo para ganar un contrato y luego aumenta los precios a través de enmiendas del contrato durante su implementación.</li>
              <li>Mala planificación en los procesos de adjudicación. En algunos casos se subestima el costo del bien y servicio, reportando un monto de adjudicación muy pequeño con respecto al monto final del contrato.</li>
            </p>/>
        <InfoCard
          info=<p>
            <li>ID de adjudicación</li>
            <li>Monto de adjudicación</li>
            <li>ID del contrato</li>
            <li>Monto del contrato</li>
          </p>
        />
        <CalculationCard info="(Monto de contrato final - monto de adjudicación) / (monto de adjudicación)"/>
      </TabPanel>
      <TabPanel value={props.val} index={4}>
        <TitleCard title="Alto porcentaje de contratos con enmiendas"/>
        <PhaseCard phase="Contrato" icon=<AssignmentSharpIcon/>/>
        <RedFlagCard
          info=<p>Un mayor número de contratos sin enmiendas puede indicar mayor integridad. La inestabilidad de un contrato puede ser un indicador de corrupción en ciertos casos; la integridad generalmente se maximiza cuando los términos finales de la licitación, adjudicación, contrato inicial y contrato final se corresponden estrechamente. El riesgo de las enmiendas es que los proveedores pueden ser seleccionados por haber ofrecido el precio más bajo y luego aumentan sus precios. Ésta es una forma legalmente permitida que facilita irregularidades en el proceso de contratación, como tal es difícil de monitorear y disminuye la integridad del proceso de compra pública.</p>/>
        <InfoCard
          info=<p>
            <li>ID del contrato</li>
            <li>Enmiendas al contrato</li>
          </p>
        />
        <CalculationCard info="Contratos con enmiendas/ todos los contratos"/>
      </TabPanel>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The error belongs to the **makeStyles** component imported from material-ui. I thougth it was a problem with the rendering, so that there a hook rule was being violated:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

This is my App.js code:

```
import './App.css';
import NavBar from './components/NavBar/NavBar';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);
  const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  };

  return(
    <div className='Background-color'>
      <NavBar
        val={value}
        changed={handleChange}
      />
    </div>
  );

}

//ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('#root'));

export default App;
```

After doing a lot of research I figured out this error is displayed when you got the incorrect react and react-dom version, so I have been trying to update from 16.13.1 to 16.8.0 version (the one with react hooks!).

Now, I tried to do it in so many different ways, and, as the following image shows, it is not updating:

[react and react-dom not updating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bRfI.png)

I tried changing **makeStyles** for **withStyles**, but this doesn't work. I tried using the commands `npm install --save --save-exact react@^16.8.0 react-dom@^16.8.0`. I tried changing the **package.json** file manually, and nothing works. I'm sure it's a version issue because I copied my code in sandbox, and there it works fine (with react 16.8.0).

I truly appreciate any new ideas! Thanks a lot.

Comment: React 16.13.1 is **later** than React 16.8.0. You shouldn't downgrade to 16.8.0. React 16.13.1 fully supports hooks and has many bug fixes compared to 16.8.0.

Comment: My two cents, you can try to delete node_modules and package-lock.json and try to reinstall modules.